# set image size for thumbnail image generated using AVAssetImageGenerator ios

Tags: ios, xcode, assets, avassetimagegenerator

I was using `AVAssetImageGenerator` class for generating thumbnail image but problem is i need to fit that thumbnail image into `UITableViewCell` having `UIImageView` of size (320,239).
I specified `AVAssetImageGenerator` maximum size property as (320,239) but i was not getting desired size what i specified please any help thanks in advance. Please look at the following code for quick reference.

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:self.consenteeVideoUrl options:nil];

AVAssetImageGenerator *gen = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

gen.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 239);

gen.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeProductionAperture;

gen.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600);

NSError *error = nil;

CMTime actualTime;

CGImageRef image = [gen copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

UIImage *thumbnailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
//thumbnailImage = [CSUtilities imageWithImage:thumbnailImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 239)];
CGImageRelease(image);
```

One more solution i got from "stackoverflow" but not much helpful in my scenario.`

```
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:self.consenteeVideoUrl options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;

CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
    }

    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:im];
    //save image to application directory...
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.uniqueCodeString];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath  withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",self.uniqueCodeString]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage);
    BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
    if (success) {
        CSLog(@"sucess");
    }
    partnerEvent.thumbnailImageStr = [self getImagePath];
    [self.ibPartnerEventTableView reloadData];
 };

 CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 239);
 generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
 [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong in your code, but as stated in the documentation

> AVAssetImageGenerator scales images such that they fit within the
>   defined bounding box. Images are never scaled up. The aspect ratio of
>   the scaled image is defined by the apertureMode property.

Since the `apertureMode` is set to `AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeProductionAperture` images generated keeps the aspect ratio. it will only fit the maximum size if the the video and the size set have the same aspect ratio, and this will unlikely to happen with the size specified.
Try to change the `UIImageView` `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` some content could be cropped but you will fill the entire imageView

Comment: ,thanks for quick replay i knew about this, maximum size depends on aspect ratios,i have one more doubt how to set the frame time using CMTimeMakeWithSeconds.Please explain about this i read the documentation but still not clear.Suppose i need to take the frame after 3 seconds how to set it can you explain thanks in advance

Comment: The meaning of CMTime is very deep, if you want to have more info about it (and you should) here is a tutorial http://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime. Once you read it you can understand that for grab a frame after 3sec you can easily get using CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(3.0, 1);

Comment: Grazie Andrea, I was just looking how to maintain the aspect using AVAssetImageGenerator!